# clojure test case assertion failure for is

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, assertions

I have a simple function `hello` in my source.

```
(defn hello [n] (str "Hello" n))
```

In the test case I am calling the `hello` function. But seems like it is returning `nil`. Test case:

```
(deftest test    (testing "string"
    ;(is (= "Hello x" (ql/hello "x")))))
    (is (= (ql/hello "x") "Hello x"))))
```

I am getting the following error.

```
expected: (= (ql/hello "x") "Hello x")
  actual: (not (= nil "Hello x"))
```

Why is it returning `nil`? If I call the `hello` function from repl I get "Hello x" followed by `nil`, but I think it is due to repl right? When I call `hello` from another function, shouldn't it return the string? I am running the test case from repl directly and not using lein.

Comment: I didn't get `nil` in repl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description it seems that your actual `hello` function was defined as:

```
(defn hello [n]
  (println "Hello" n))
```

When you run `(hello "x")` it prints `Hello x` to the console and returns `nil` (that's the behaviour of `println`).

To get your test passing you need to redefine your function in the REPL so it matches your version with `str` instead of `println`.

```
boot.user=> (require '[clojure.test :refer :all])
nil
boot.user=> (defn hello [n]
       #_=>   (println "Hello" n))
#'boot.user/hello
boot.user=> (is (= "Hello x" (hello "x")))
Hello x

FAIL in () (boot.user5664236129068656247.clj:1)
expected: (= "Hello x" (hello "x"))
  actual: (not (= "Hello x" nil))
false
boot.user=> (defn hello [n]
       #_=>   (str "Hello " n))
#'boot.user/hello
boot.user=> (is (= "Hello x" (hello "x")))
true
boot.user=>
```